# React - one state for managing 'active' flag on multiple compontents

Tags: reactjs, react-props, use-state

I have a list of compontents I want to share the same state.

I want, at any given time, only the last selected component to have the active state whilst the others to be 'inactive'.

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-herschel-q3spm?file=/src/App.js)

Thanks.

EDIT:
for SO future proofing of potential dead links:

SidebarList Compontent:

```
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  const handleActive = (i) => {
    console.log(i);
    i.currentTarget.className = active ? "a" : "b";
    console.log(i.currentTarget.className);
  };

  const list = props.items.map((item) => {
    return (
      <ListItem key={item.id} handleActive={(item) => handleActive(item)}>
        {item.text}{" "}
      </ListItem>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="sidebar__list">
      <h2>{props.title}</h2>
      <ul>{list}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

ListItem compontent

```
function List_item(props) {
  return (
    <li onClick={props.handleActive}>
      <a>
        <h2>{props.children}</h2>
      </a>
    </li>
  );
}

export default List_item;
```

And the App component:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SidebarList
        title="About"
        items={[
          { id: 1, text: "Item 1 arr" },
          { id: 2, text: "Item 2 arr" }
        ]}
      />
      <SidebarList
        title="Templates"
        items={[
          { id: 1, text: "Item 1 arr" },
          { id: 2, text: "Item 2 arr" }
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; react router v4 NavLink perform singular maintenance of one active className, dependant on the current routed page.

NavLink property 'activeClassName' will parse a specfied className to the current routed page, whilst removing on non-routed pages. All state management in this question is therefore redundant.